# SQL Transaction not committing to database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am writing my first SQL transaction code and have scoured stackoverflow to make sure I've done it right. The basic idea of the project is to get an email, parse it into a RawDatum object, then write the contents of the object to the SQL database. I was hoping to commit the new rows in batches of 100.

I have the code running without errors, but nothing is being actually written to the database.

I have a local DB (MS SQL Server Express). I have a few things commented out for testing purposes. What am I doing wrong?

```
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.MissionMetricsConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO RawData (MessageUID, DateTime, Attribute, DigitalValue, AnalogValue) VALUES (@MessageUID, @DateTime, @Attribute, @DigitalValue, @AnalogValue)";
            command.Parameters.Add("@MessageUID", SqlDbType.Int);
            command.Parameters.Add("@DateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            command.Parameters.Add("@Attribute", SqlDbType.Text);
            command.Parameters.Add("@DigitalValue", SqlDbType.Bit);
            command.Parameters.Add("@AnalogValue", SqlDbType.Float);
            command.Connection = connection;

            RawDatum currentDatum = null;
            int uid;
            List<int> uidsToDelete = new List<int>();
            int numLoops = 1;//(int)(ids.Length / loopSize) + 1;

            for (var loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < numLoops; loopIndex++)
            {
                int startIndex = loopIndex * loopSize;
                int endIndex = 10;// Math.Min((loopIndex + 1) * loopSize, ids.Length);
                using (SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        command.Transaction = transaction;
                        for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
                        {
                            msg = inbox.Fetch.MessageObject(ids[i]);
                            uid = inbox.Fetch.Uid(ids[i]);
                            if (msg.Subject == "[METRICS]")
                            {
                                currentDatum = new RawDatum(uid, msg.Date, msg.BodyText.TextStripped);
                                command.Parameters["@MessageUID"].Value = currentDatum.MessageUid;
                                command.Parameters["@DateTime"].Value = currentDatum.DateTime;
                                command.Parameters["@Attribute"].Value = currentDatum.Attribute;
                                command.Parameters["@DigitalValue"].Value = currentDatum.DigitalValue;
                                command.Parameters["@AnalogValue"].Value = currentDatum.AnalogValue;
                                int queryResult = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                if (queryResult != 1)
                                {
                                    throw new InvalidProgramException();
                                }
                            }
                            uidsToDelete.Add(uid);
                        }
                        transaction.Commit();
                        //Delete(uidsToDelete);
                        output[1] += uidsToDelete.Count;
                        uidsToDelete.Clear();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        output[0] += 1;
                        output[2] += endIndex - startIndex;
                    }
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Have you set breakpoints to ensure it's not throwing an exception, leaving you in the catch block to rollback things?  (General 'catch' blocks that catch all exceptions like that are generally a bad coding practice... you should be catching the SqlException you're expecting if something goes wrong, but that's another issue).

Comment: How do you know it isn't throwing errors? Your catch will rollback your transaction and update a couple values in your output array (whatever that is).

Comment: why are you splitting the cmd.Parameters and adding the type then the value when you can do all this in a single line with the `Paramteres.Add()` method of the Command Object.. makes this code really hard to read.. clean up you code I would refactor the existing ..

Comment: I have checked it's not rolling back. @MethodMan, I need to change the parameter value per iteration without adding a new parameter. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: you are not changing the parameters.. you are changing the value and yes you can do that I do not see the actual Parameters being changed you're only inserting per iteration based on the values of the params being changed.. check out the `Command.Parameters.Add()` method overloads..

Comment: This ended up being a debug database over-write issue, so I was looking at the wrong database for updates. Thanks for all the pointers, though.